# MYSQL INSERT IF SUMs > CONSTANT

Tags: mysql, if-statement, insert, sum, where-clause

I'm trying to insert a record if a sum of 3 user columns from 2 tables exceeds a constant.

I've searched all over, found you can't put user variables in `IF`s, `WHERE`'s etc.  Found you can't put `SUM`s in `IF`s, `WHERE`'s etc.  I'm at a total loss.  Here's an example of my earlier bad code before unsuccessfully trying to use `SUM`s in `WHERE`s, if it helps:

```
SELECT SUM(num1) INTO @mun1 FROM table1 WHERE user = '0';

SELECT SUM(num2) INTO @mun2 FROM table1 WHERE user = '0';

SELECT SUM(num3) INTO @mun3 FROM table2 WHERE column1 = 'd' AND user = '0';

SET @mun4 = @mun1 - @mun2 - @mun3;

INSERT INTO table2 (user, column1, column2) VALUES ('0', 'd', '100') WHERE @mun4 >= 100;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (user, column1, column2) 
select '0', 'd', '100'
from dual
where (SELECT SUM(num1 + num2) FROM table1 WHERE user = '0') +
      (SELECT SUM(num3) FROM table2 WHERE column1 = 'd' AND user = '0') > 100;
```

This is a case of the general solution for a "insert if condition" problem:

```
insert into ... select ... where condition
```

The select will only return rows if the condition is true, and importantly, will return no rows if false - meaning the insert only happens if the condition is true, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your quick reply.  Now, I'm getting "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (SELECT SUM(..." at the first WHERE.  It's similar to errors I've received in my past attempts.

Answer (score 1):

This is same as @Bohemian's answer, but you got to add a `LIMIT` clause to  stop inserting multiple records, since select clause may return multiple records

```
INSERT INTO table2 (user, column1, column2) 
SELECT      '0', 'd', '100'
   FROM dual
   WHERE 
         (SELECT SUM(num1 - num2) FROM table1 WHERE user = '0')
         (SELECT SUM(num3) FROM table2 WHERE column1 = 'd' AND user = '0') > 
         100 
   LIMIT 1
```